# Excessive Execution Time

Tags: t-sql, query

Context:
I have written a t-sql query that works perfectly if I do not use a SELECT with a combining of 2 columns (txtSubID and txtSubmitByInitials). The problem is, I need to combine the 2 columns to make a unique identifier. I work at a school and we often have more than 1 teacher to a class, but both teachers must input grades. I am writing a query to help me identify those that have not put in their grades. I am combining the teachers initials with the class name to create a unique identifier to then use to ascertain who has not done their grades.

My query runs in less than 2 seconds if I remove the combined column in the first SELECT (Grades) and just have it as txtSubID. It fails to run (left for over 30 mins) if I have the combined column. I don't understand why adding in this combined column is causing the SQL to then fail. Any help appreciated as it is driving me mad.

```
WITH Grades
AS (
    SELECT [txtSubID] + [txtSubmitByInitials] AS SetID
        ,[txtCurrentSubjectReportName] AS SubjectName
        ,[txtGradingName]
        ,txtSubmitByPreName + ' ' + [txtSubmitBySurname] AS SubmittedBy
    FROM [iSAMS].[dbo].[VwReportsManagementAcademicReports]
    WHERE intReportCycleID = 385
        AND intReportProgress = 1
        AND intNCYear = 12
        AND (
            txtGradingName LIKE 'attainment'
            OR txtGradingName LIKE 'effort%'
            )
    )
    ,AttainmentCount
AS (
    SELECT COUNT(Grades.SetID) AS AttainmentCount
        ,Grades.SetID AS SetID
    FROM Grades
    WHERE Grades.txtGradingName = 'Attainment'
    GROUP BY Grades.SetID
    )
    ,EffortHW
AS (
    SELECT COUNT(Grades.SetID) AS EffortHWCount
        ,Grades.SetID AS SetID
    FROM Grades
    WHERE Grades.txtGradingName = 'Effort Homework'
    GROUP BY Grades.SetID
    )
    ,EffortCW
AS (
    SELECT COUNT(Grades.SetID) AS EffortCWCount
        ,Grades.SetID AS SetID
    FROM Grades
    WHERE Grades.txtGradingName = 'Effort Classwork'
    GROUP BY Grades.SetID
    )
SELECT Grades.SubjectName
    ,Grades.SubmittedBy
    ,AttainmentCount.AttainmentCount
    ,EffortHW.EffortHwCount
    ,EffortCW.EffortCWCount
    ,AttainmentCount.SetID
FROM Grades
INNER JOIN EffortHW ON Grades.SetID = EffortHW.SetID
INNER JOIN EffortCW ON Grades.SetID = EffortCW.SetID
INNER JOIN AttainmentCount ON Grades.SetID = AttainmentCount.SetID
GROUP BY Grades.SubjectName
    ,Grades.SubmittedBy
    ,AttainmentCount.AttainmentCount
    ,EffortHW.EffortHwCount
    ,EffortCW.EffortCWCount
    ,AttainmentCount.SetID
ORDER BY AttainmentCount.SetID
```

Comment: Use conditional counting `(SUM(CASE WHEN txtGradingName = 'value' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))`. 2) Your `Grades.SetID` can't be NULL, hence you may use `COUNT(*)`. 3) Replace `AttainmentCount.SetID` in outer query with `Grades.SetID`. 4) Perform all calculations in outer query - CTEs are excess there.

Comment: [How To Get Answers To SQL Server Performance Questions](https://www.erikdarling.com/how-to-get-answers-to-sql-server-performance-questions/)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you could clean up this code significantly, and do it all in a single scan of the base table.

- Instead of multiple CTEs, just do a single `GROUP BY` with conditional aggregation.
- Then instead of joining that back to the original, just merge the aggregation into the outer query.
- Instead of grouping by a concatentation, group by its individual components, which allows the server to potentially hit an index. Then just concatenate in the `SELECT`.

```
SELECT
     g.txtCurrentSubjectReportName AS SubjectName
    ,g.txtSubmitByPreName + ' ' + g.txtSubmitBySurname AS SubmittedBy
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN g.txtGradingName = 'Attainment'       THEN 1 END) AS AttainmentCount
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN g.txtGradingName = 'Effort Homework'  THEN 1 END) AS EffortHwCount
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN g.txtGradingName = 'Effort Classwork' THEN 1 END) AS EffortCWCount
    ,g.txtSubID + g.txtSubmitByInitials AS SetID
FROM Grades g
GROUP BY
     g.txtCurrentSubjectReportName 
    ,g.txtSubmitByPreName
    ,g.txtSubmitBySurname
    ,g.txtSubID
    ,g.txtSubmitByInitials
ORDER BY AttainmentCount.SetID
```